# Shopify page keep refreshing after being redirected by javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools, shopify

I am trying to create a website https://fone-kase-plus.myshopify.com/ that will detect what device model it's being accessed from (for example GALAXY A40) so it will immediately redirect the user to a corresponding page.
It seems to be working, but it will reload the page multiple times after redirecting. If I try to redirect it to non-shopify page (eg stackoverflow.com) this problem doesn't occur.

function deviceAPIcallback(result){
         
           if(result.deviceName == "desktop"){
               window.location.href = "https://fone-kase-plus.myshopify.com/pages/galaxy-a40";
           }
        
           else{
               alert(result.deviceName);
           }
        
        }

Can you please tell me what the problem can be or at least how I can detect it by dev tools?
Thanks

Comment: Could it be your including the function also on the target page? To use Dev Tools to catch errors you can use *Preserve log* on the *Network* tab.

Answer (score 0):

When I go to the site from both my macOS laptop and my iPhone I only get the alert aspect of your function. What does `result.deviceName` return? You might need to add a third '=' to your first 'if' statement.

```
function deviceAPIcallback(result) {
    if(result.deviceName === "desktop") {
        window.location.href = 'https...';
    } else { 
        alert(result.deviceName);
    }
}
```